# How do I change from kanban to scrum in Taiga.IO?

Tags: taiga

I've just started using [taiga](https://taiga.io) to manage some personal projects and I created my first scrum project, but then I realised that the way I'm approaching this project is more suited to kanban.

How do I change between project types? I can't find a setting that says 'switch project types' anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no master 'switch'. Taiga seems to hold a view of your project that's agnostic to how you display it (separation of concern!). Enabling either view is done via modules.

Here's a picture:

[image: Modules page of Taiga]

Just enable the one you want.